# Let $f:A\to N$, show that if there exists $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ we have $b\in \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

I have the following exercise:

Let $f:A\to N$, show that if there exists $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ we have $b\in \overline{f(A)}$

I don't know what $b$ is meant to be, there's a typo in this exercise. I think it's supposed to be the following:

Let $f:A\to N$, show that if there exists $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\color{Red}{=b}$ we have $b\in \overline{f(A)}$

Does that makes sense to you? What does this question means? How to prove it?

Comment: I agree that probably $b$ is supposed to be $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$. To solve the problem, what's the definition of $\overline{f(A)}$? What's the definition of $b = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$? Do these somehow correspond?

Comment: $f(A)$ is the image of $f$. $\overline{f(A)}$ is the closure of the image. I somehow need to prove that the limit of a function is in the closure. For me, the closure is the set of points that has a distance $=0$ from the set, which I do not think it's useful for my proof

Comment: It will be more helpful to use a different definition of closure. Let $X$ be a topological space and $S$ be a subset of $X$. A *limit point* of $S$ is some point $x \in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $S$ at some point other than $x$. The closure of $S$ is the union of $S$ and all of its limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: A \to N$ and $b:= \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$. If $b \in f(A)$ you are done, so we will suppose not. Let $N_b$ be any neighborhood of $b$. Suppose $N_b \cap f(A) = \emptyset$. By definition of $b$, given any neighborhood $U_b \subset N$, there exists a corresponding $V_a \subset A$ s.t $f(V_a) \subset U_b$. Now just take $N_b = U_b$ and you have a contradiction. Thus, $b \in \overline{f(A)}$ as desired.